# Calling a function for which assembly states "Public Sub [Operator]"?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I'm dealing with a dll for which I don't have any example source code in VB.NET.
The assembly tells me that the sub that I would like to call looks like this:

```
Public Sub [Operator](image As MatrixBase, ByRef detections As IEnumerable(Of RectDetection), Optional threshold As Double = 0)
```

I would like to know if I really have to call it like this:

```
 SomeClass.Operator(SomeInput)
```

The word "Operator" makes me nervous.

Is there a more beautiful way to do that?

Thank you.

FYI, this is the entire assembly of the DLL:

```
#Region "Assembly DlibDotNet, Version=19.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
' D:\Dev\Projects\faceshift\faceshift\packages\DlibDotNet.19.15.0.20180916\lib\netstandard2.0\DlibDotNet.dll
#End Region

Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace DlibDotNet
    Public NotInheritable Class FrontalFaceDetector
        Inherits DlibObject

        Public Sub [Operator](image As MatrixBase, ByRef detections As IEnumerable(Of RectDetection), Optional threshold As Double = 0)
        Protected Overrides Sub DisposeUnmanaged()

        Public Function [Operator](image As Array2DBase, Optional threshold As Double = 0) As Rectangle()
        Public Function [Operator](image As MatrixBase, Optional threshold As Double = 0) As Rectangle()
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: The square brackets are how VB allows you to escape reserved words so that you can give something a name that would otherwise not be allowed.  Typically, it's used for interop with something from a different language where the name is not reserved.  If you have a case where you need the square brackets, then you really need them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason as to why the word `Operator` makes you nervous so I can't address that, but like its declaration you can call the method with the square brackets:

```
FrontalFaceDetector.[Operator]( ... )
```

Personally I like it better without them, though.